# How to add sort(descending and ascending) in symfony2 twig file using select tag and display result in table?

Tags: php, symfony, sorting

I am currently working on a project using symfony2 framework. My problem is all about on how can I order by  or sort in my twig file. Scenario look something like this, I add a select tag in my twig file with the choices (like this [Ascending and Descending inside a select tag](http://jsfiddle.net/37w353px/))

And now, how can I add the choices, that whenever I choose the descending it will be ordered as descending and so with the ascending. I mean here , in the table

I already use `ORDER BY` in my repository.

Here is my repository.

```
 public function getTransactions($page = 1, $limit = 10) {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
          'SELECT partial a.{supplierTransactionDetailId, rNumber, pNumber,  amount}, 
          partial b.{supplierTransactionId, transactionDate, senderId, receiverId}, 
          partial c.{supplierDocTypeId, docsType} 
          FROM SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail a 
          JOIN a.supplierTransaction b 
          JOIN b.supplierDocType c
          ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc'
          )
        ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) *$limit )
        ->setMaxResults($limit);

        $paginator = new Paginator ($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false );
        $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);

        return $paginator ;
      }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Sample table structure :

```
Transaction Date  Rnumber   PNumber   Amount
2015Aug26         1346565   1245465   900
2015Aug25         2546576   1436565   8567
2015Aug20         4324656   3654735   1000
```

The table will display something like this since the default order is Descending. The upper part of the table is my select tag and selected as default is descending but once Ascending is click or selected, the table must display in ascending order.

Comment: @Barmar: Can you help me with this one?

Comment: One solution would be to pass the sort order as a parameter to your controller and then to your repository function.

Comment: @plbit: can u give example on how should i do it since I am just new to this,,?? thanks a lot,,, appreciate your help.